# Get only the number from the string that appears in the last part of the string

Tags: python, pandas, string

```
import pandas as pd

mydata = {"Key" : [567, 568, 569, 570, 571, 572] , "Sprint" : ["Max1", "Max2", "DI001 2", "DI001 25", "DAS 100" , "DI001 101"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(mydata)
print (df)
```

From this data frame `df` I would like to split only the number which appears in the last part of the string. Splitting the string doesn't work as the number of digits at the end is not pre-defined. It can be up to 3 digits.

Expected output: in the column "Sprint Number", data should appear as given below.

[image: Expected Output for column "Sprint Number"]

Comment: Please [don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution with `str.extract`.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> mydata = {
...     "Key": [567, 568, 569, 570, 571, 572],
...     "Sprint": ["Max1", "Max2", "DI001 2", "DI001 25", "DAS 100", "DI001 101"],
... }
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(mydata)
>>> print(df)
   Key     Sprint
0  567       Max1
1  568       Max2
2  569    DI001 2
3  570   DI001 25
4  571    DAS 100
5  572  DI001 101
>>> df["Sprint Number"] = df.Sprint.str.extract(r"(\d+)$").astype(int)
>>> print(df)
   Key     Sprint Sprint Number
0  567       Max1             1
1  568       Max2             2
2  569    DI001 2             2
3  570   DI001 25            25
4  571    DAS 100           100
5  572  DI001 101           101
```

Comment: `(?:\b)?` is pretty useless here. Perhaps replace it with `(?<=\D)` (though then it won't work for a string which consists entirely of a number; but then, just say `(\d+)$` if that's what you mean).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Maybe you should append `.astype(int)` since you are extracting the numbers?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM  
if the dataset Sprint column is having multiple value with ";" separator. now as first step, will split the string into a list and then I want to extract the numbers and put into another list in column "Sprintnum"     


Key   |  Sprint             |   sprintlist | Sprintnumb
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 567 | Max1;Max2 |  [Max1, Max2] | [1, 2] |